# Weblogic upgrade wizard - security provider

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I am upgrading weblogic 10.3.5 to 12.1.1, and to d so, I am using weblogic upgrade wizard.

I started with upgrading security providers using command - `java -classpath /localdata/weblogic/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Upgrade -type securityproviders`

But it displays "Upgrading old security providers to new 10.3 providers", while I am running it from weblogic 12.1.1 and want to upgrade to this version.

Logs printed are :

> Calling Wizard framework for upgrade: args2: [-mode=gui, -file=wcf/plugin_gui_wizard.xml, -log=stdout, -p:plugin:plugin.executionPlan.file=weblogic/upgrade/upgradesecurityproviders/execplan.xml, -p:plugin:I18N_PLUGIN=weblogic/upgrade/i18n_upgrade, -p:plugin:TARGET_VERSION=12.1.1.0]

I cross verified, on which version I am running upgrade wizard using `java -classpath /localdata/weblogic/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.version` and it shows,

> WebLogic Server 12.1.1.0  Wed Dec 7 08:40:57 PST 2011 1445491

Snapshot is :

[image]

And snapshot from doc provided by Oracle (where it shows 12.1 wizard) is :

[image]

**Note :** If I proceed and select **source directory as 10.3 mbeantypes and destination directory as 12.1 mbeantypes**, wizard shows error as below for all jars (not showing all line) :

> Not upgrading commo.dtd because either this is an out-of-the-box Oracle security provider JAR or this security provider JAR is already upgraded or this is not a valid archive file (may not be a .jar).
>
> No security provider JARs have been upgraded.

and similar for other jars too.

Any idea what I would have missed? Am i following wrong approach?

Comment: Can you add the `-out` option like `java weblogic.Upgrade -type securityproviders [-out file]` ? It seems like your weblogic.home or mw.home is being set incorrectly and defaulting to the 10.3 install. The .out file will probably have some classpath info that helps debug

Comment: Does not `TARGET_VERSION=12.1.1.0` printed on console means, it is pointing to v12?